# Error in deleting a node from circular linked list

Tags: python

I wrote  a function to delete a  node from circular linked list when a value is given:

```
def delete_node(head, value):
    p=head
    if p is None:
        return None
    while p.value!=value:
        p=p.next
        if p.next is head and p.value!=value:
            return head
    p.value=p.next.value
    if p.next==head:
        head=p
    p.next=p.next.next
    return head
```

it is working for some inputs while not for others.ex:`delete_node(range(1,5),5)`,it was returning a wrong list.
The method I use for converting a list to circular linked list:

```
def to_circular_list(plist):
head = None
tail = None
for element in plist:
    node = Node(element)
    if not head:
        head = node
    else:
        tail.next = node
    tail = node

if tail:
    tail.next = head
return head
```

where plist can be range(1,5) in this case.
the class for creating a node:

```
class Node(object):
def __init__(self,value=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next = None
```

Comment: `range(1,5)` is not a circular linked list

Comment: I gave just to give an idea on what data I try to implement. I already have a method to covert range(1,5) to a circular linked list and it works perfectly@thg435

Comment: share your method then

Comment: I shared it in the question now.@thg435